# PHP Unit - echo inside my class is not displaying any output

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm using Zend Studio to Unit Test my classes

I've echo's inside the class I'm testing (Not the TestClass)

Can't see any output in "Browser Output" or "Debug" tab while running as Unit Test

Comment: Might be a version issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790271/echo-in-phpunit-tests

Comment: there shouldn't be `echo` in your classes

Comment: are you using process isolation?

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: @ThomasKelley It's a version problem, I guess, mine is 3.6.10 that comes with Zend Studio, I've tried updating the product but no success, how can we update Zend Studio to use a newer version

Comment: This must not be an issue of PHPUnit. This can be just your Zend Studio configuration. Please contact the vendor of that software for your support options, they should be able to tell you if Zend Studio (your version) has support for output with their Phpunit integration. In earlier versions of Zend Studio you would see the output in the *Debug Output Tab*. But I can not offer Zend Studio support here.